# Why aren't these strings equal?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have the below coding, i am make sure that if condition is TRUE, but i can't get into it.
i prove it by using NSLog write the value and length before and after step to the if statements, both equal to "test" and length = 4, anyone can solve my problem?

And please take a look below link which is my cap screen, please help, Thanks !!!!

http://postimage.org/image/rvtxcq1g1/

```
NSLog(@"Before value=%@, lenght=%i", txtMaster.text, [txtMaster.text length]);

if (txtMaster.text == @"test")
{
   NSLog(@"%@\n", @"Success");
}

NSLog(@"After value=%@, lenght=%i", txtMaster.text, [txtMaster.text length]);
```

Comment: Please do not use "SOS" in your question titles. I've edited that out of both of your recent questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `==` to compare `NSString`s compares the pointer value of the strings. That's probably not what you want. Instead, try this:

```
if([txtMaster.text isEqualToString:@"test"]) {
    NSLog(@"Success!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have some questions about pointers.

@"test" returns a pointer that shows where the constant string exists in memory .

- @"test"        = 0xC0001. At the 0xC0001 adress it's the constant
  string @"test"
- txtMaster.text = 0xD3401. At the 0xD3401 adress it's an object
  (probably NSString)

In rare case that @"test"  and txtMaster.text are equal (==) then that means

- txtMaster.txt = @"test" = same address = 0xd32901 and they point on
  the same object.

Remember all methods that return Objective-C objects usual return pointers on thoses objects.

I hope the fog is leaving now..